# Javascript embedded in HTML or javascript in external file?

Tags: javascript

I will need to write lots of different types of javascript code soon using lots of different features.
For example:

```
def function example()
```

etc. 
What are the Pros and cons of using javascript in html or in an external file?
I need lots of Pros and Cons before I can fully make up my mind

Comment: Thank you, I am very grateful for all of these detailed answers :) I would use the plus arrows on them but don't have enough status to do that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biggest pro's of external JS files are

1. It will keep your code clean.
2. Easier maintenance.
3. Multiple pages can use those scripts.
4. Performance increases as it can be  easily cached by browsers.
5. You can easily minify JS files it they are seperated.

Cons if you combine JS and HTML code

Just opposite to above points

Answer (score 1):

Main difference is that if you write JavaScript externally then your code will be clean and will be easy for you to understand it in future

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid having JS in your HTML file. I don't see the benefit of it being in there. It just takes space for what should be inside of your HTML file: HTML. Having it in an external file is creating clean and readable code for yourself and anybody who will be reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in both HTML and External file, however our main aim while writing a code is to reduce page load time, i.e to reduce http request.

If your script is really short and you are calling it in your page only once or twice then it is better to keep it just before end of body tag. It reduces extra http request.

If you have many functions and calling multiple times in your page then better to use an external file. It will be cached in your browser once loaded, so when you visit next time, page load will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

To my personal opinion the very best way to go about it

1. is to create a clean content of the document and make sure all information is there and immediately accessible by the client request.
2. Than make sure you have properly formatted the content and have created the best structure possible by tagging it with proper clean and absolutely error-free html
3. Than make sure you make the best use of CSS presentation code progressively reaching for advanced features only when absolutely necessary, give as much as possible style definitions on global selectors, reusability and consistence to maintain integrity continuity format semiology throughout the set. Never forget to define font size and family on top parent which is traditionally the body of document. And this is the most important thing and very painful to learn when coding and designing html.
4. After you have made sure your data/information can be properly accessed as is then you begin adding muscles and interactivity to it, that is JavaScript.

In JavaScript programming development phase, you start by writing the code inside the document source. Then after debugging and testing your successful code on at least 4 major browsers, you can start moving these blocks of code where you see them fit. There are two general types of your js-code the code that manipulates DOM content and style and structure and the code that doesn't.

If the given functionality, response and style is highly specific to the current page/application there is absolutely no benefit in physically separating your js-code from the document. But there is a cleaning step you'd prefer to take after all is up and running. That's where you would like to move all your javascript collection of methods and probably a small private lib which do not depend on DOM availability, up to the document head. Leaving all the rest at the bottom of your body element.

But this is when and where you would think - is it better if I move the script from the document head to an external file instead of leaving it take space in head holding back the speed of my content load?

It is. But than you should preferably move the script source element back to the document body and insert it jus before the opening of the existing on-page code which depends on these methods. Only the before load script operations should remain on document head at all times (mostly feature detection methods).

This is applicable on very simple and small set of pages otherwise reusable code and functionality as much as possible with the given content will demand from you to move them all in a (again more preferably, single) external file(s). Minimizing server requests. Because once loaded all other pages will draw from the cash.

p.s.: I apologize on possible typing errors or if I left an unfinished thought or a sentence writing this draft.
Regards.